# How to fix Server failed to start on the CLI Servers tab of Angular IDE

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-ide

I created an Angular project with Angular IDE 2017 CI.

- Angular CLI version: Latest(6.1.1)
- Node.js version : Use system installation (10.7.0)
- NPM version : Use system installation (6.1.0)

The project is created  correctly. Then in the eclipse servers tab I tried to start the application but a problem occurred. I received a dialog box that says "Server failed to start" and In the console I got this error:

> "C:/Users/user1/Workspaces/Angular IDE 2017
>   CI/MyProject/node_modules/angular-ide/bin/ng" serve --port=4200
>   --live-reload=true --webclipse-la unch-id=5846270484319258659 C:/Users/user1\Workspaces\Angular IDE 2017
>   CI\MyProject\node_modules\angular-ide\lib\CLUtils.js:11 let
>   ngCLIPKGName = null; ^^^
>
> SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class)
>   not yet supported outside strict mode
>       at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:414:25)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:313:12)
>       at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
>       at require (module.js:385:17)
>       at Object. (C:\Users\user1\Workspaces\Angular IDE 2017 CI\MyProject\node_modules\angular-ide\bin\ng:7:26)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)